# Multiple selection from SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to write a query to return multiple matching results,I want to see how many record match a column from a table.

```
select  [pomDocumentId],
        [svPartNo],
        count(svPartNo) as dup
from [tbl_ODW_PomItem] 
group by [svPartNo],[pomDocumentId]
```

I tried this,but won't work. I am trying to see how many `[pomDocumentId]` matches a `[svPartNo]` in the table.

Thank you.

```
id          pomDocumentId          svPartNo

4955        8298                   5WK96132-E
6131        14826                  5WK96132-E
```

Here is the query that solved the problem:

```
select [svPartNo], count(svPartNo) as dup 
  from [ODW_Dev].[dbo].[tbl_ODW_PomItem]
   group by [svPartNo]  
   having count(svPartNo)>1 
   order by dup desc
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: `where [svPartNo] = [pomDocumentId]` ?

Comment: That's the thing,they're not equal.

Comment: What is a "match" then?

Comment: What is the matching condition here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're after a simple `GROUP BY` with `COUNT`, run the below SQL to test with your sample data:

```
DECLARE @tbl_ODW_PomItem AS TABLE 
    ([id] int, [pomDocumentId] int, [svPartNo] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO @tbl_ODW_PomItem
    ([id], [pomDocumentId], [svPartNo])
VALUES
    (4955, 8298, '5WK96132-E'),
    (6131, 14826, '5WK96132-E')
;


SELECT COUNT(pomDocumentId) DocCount, svPartNo
FROM @tbl_ODW_PomItem
GROUP BY svPartNo
```

This produces:

```
DocCount    svPartNo
======================
2           5WK96132-E
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
  SELECT svPartNo, COUNT(pomDocumentId) FROM TAB GROUP BY svPartNo
```